# Is it possible to delete items from a list in a loop using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use a list in order to append to a pandas data frame. In the process of this, I want to append the values from the list to the dataframe and then delete the values in the list, where it is then meant to repeat in a loop.

However, what it does instead is register the last pair of inputs given, there are no error values it simply does not include the other values I put in. What am I doing wrong, and do I need to do something completely different.
Thanks

```
n = int(input("\nhow big is the sample size?:   "))
p = "q" 
num = 0
Sample1 = []

z = 1
for q in range (0, n):
    c = float(input(f"\tAdd the predictor# {z}:  ")) #z is to count the number of values for the list
    d = float(input(f"\tAdd the response# {z}:  "))
           
    if q > 0:      
        Sample1.append(c) # to append the values to the list
        Sample1.append(d)
        
        df.loc[len(df)] = Sample1  #to append to separate dataframe
        Sample1.clear() #to remove values of list to begin loop again
    z = z+1
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `df.loc[len(df)] = [c, d]` and drop the use of `Sample1`? Why do you start `q` at `0` but don't do anything substantial in this pass? Regarding `z`: do `for z, q in enumerate(range(0, n), start=1):` instead of incrementing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a bit and works as expected. Output:

```
n = int(input("\nhow big is the sample size?:   "))
p = "q" 
num = 0
df = pd.DataFrame({'pred':[], 'resp':[]})
z = 1
for q in range (0, n):
    c = float(input(f"\tAdd the predictor# {z}:  ")) #z is to count the number of values for the list
    d = float(input(f"\tAdd the response# {z}:  "))
           
    if q >= 0:      
        Sample=[c, d]        
        df.loc[q] = Sample
    z = z+1
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the only problem is that it does not register the last set of values given. For an example if I input 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6, 7 it would only register 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: See the answer again.